# Does SVN works like this

Tags: svn, .net, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm not a programmer. In our company, our devs (that work mainly with .NET) used to have Visual Source Safe.

With the re-install and update of all the devs computers to Windows 7 64 bit, the question of VSS came up and I noticed it was replaced for something called Windows Foundation Server which requires a separate license.

- Will a locally installed SVN server replace VSS for the purposes of version control on .NET applications ?
- Can I install a SVN server on Linux , have users use the Tortoise SVN client and have the repositories reside in a Windows File Sharing server?
  Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something you have to ask your users. Do they need some special features of VSS or TFS or would SVN be sufficient for them? We can't tell.

Comment: Our users don't know SVN. I am suggesting they have a look at it. At the same time, I (ignorant on the subject) am asking you guys (who have knowledge of SVN) if it works for .NET version control. I'm also asking other questions regarding this subject.

Comment: We aren't developers either, and I guess few people here are familiar enough with TFS and its Visual Studio integration to compare it to SVN with Tortoise (and it's [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) anyway). In the end, this really comes down to a) your developers telling you what they need and/or b) a business decision to save the TFS expenses, possibly against your users wishes.

Comment: So installing TFS and / or installing SVN and knowing their basic features is not within the scope of server fault. Is that it?

Comment: SVN is a version control system, so yes, it can do version control. That's what we know and can tell you. Can it replace VSS/TFS in your org? How should we know?

Comment: svn is so last decade. The new hotness is git. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes for your two questions. We also use SVN server and Tortoise together with a paid Visual Studio addin called VisualSVN which bridges Tortoise and SVN server right from within Visual Studio. We also considered TFS, but its too big requiring too much infrastructure and time.